# Counter in loop in foreach

Tags: categories, loop, php

I want the one **most view post**, with custom field value, in 4 categories (`foreach`).
It works. But as I use my code for a slider, I want to `echo` and active css class for the first one post of my loop.

I use a php counter, but it doesn't work. 
What I doing wrong.
Here is my code

```
$cats = array('batiments-delevage', 'logements-bovin', 'stockages-deffluents', 'soins-et-hygiene');
$exclude_posts = array();
foreach( $cats as $cat ) :
  // build query argument
  $query_args = array(
    'category_name' => $cat,
    'showposts'     => 1,
    'post_type'     => 'post',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'meta_key'      => 'wpb_post_views_count', //custom field for view count
    'orderby'       => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'         => 'DESC'
  );

  // exclude post that already have been fetched
  // this would be useful if multiple category is assigned for same post
  if( !empty($exclude_posts) )
    $query_args['post__not_in'] = $exclude_posts;

  // do query
  $query = new WP_Query( $query_args );

  if ($query->have_posts()) : // check if query have any post

    $i = 0; // start a counter for the active indicator

    while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); // start loop & set post global 
      // Get category slug parent info
      $category = get_the_category();
      $cat_slug = $category[0]->slug;
      $cat_name = $category[0]->name;
      $cat_url =  get_category_link( $category[0]->cat_ID );
      $post_date_month = get_the_date('M');
      $post_date_year = get_the_date('Y');

      $exclude_posts[] = get_the_ID();

?><div class="item <?php if ($i == 0) echo 'active'; ?>">
  <header class="header-item">
    <a class="link-img" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
      <?php the_post_thumbnail('tab-slider', array( 'class' => 'img-responsive') ); ?>
    </a>
    <div class="date-box">
      <?php
      echo $post_date_month.'<br/>';
      echo '<small>'.$post_date_year.'</small>';
    ?></div>

    </header><!-- /header -->
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h4><?php if ($i == 0) echo 'active'; ?><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
      <p class="meta-cat"><small><span class="inline-categ-icon visible-xs-block visible-sm-block icon-<?php echo $cat_slug;?>"></span>  Dans <a href="<?php echo $cat_url;?>" title="Voir les articles dans la rubrique « <?php echo $cat_name;?> » "><?php echo $cat_name;?></a></small></p>
      <p class="most-view-excerpt"><?php echo excerpt(27); ?></p>
    </div>
    <p><a class="read-more" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="Lire notre article <?php the_title(); ?>">Lire le reportage</a></p>
  </div>
  <?php $i++; endwhile; endif; ?>

<?php endforeach; ?> 
</div>
```

**Updated**
Now the right code. Thanks a lot bynicolas

```
$cats = array('batiments-delevage', 'logements-bovin', 'stockages-deffluents', 'soins-et-hygiene');
$exclude_posts = array();
$active = true;
foreach( $cats as $cat ) :
  // build query argument
  $query_args = array(
  'category_name'       => $cat,
  'posts_per_page'      => 1,
  'post_type'           => 'post',
  'post_status'         => 'publish',
  'meta_key'            => 'wpb_post_views_count', //custom field for view count
  'orderby'             => 'meta_value_num',
  'order'               => 'DESC'
);

// exclude post that already have been fetched
// this would be useful if multiple category is assigned for same post
if( !empty($exclude_posts) )
  $query_args['post__not_in'] = $exclude_posts;

  // do query
  $query = new WP_Query( $query_args );

  if ($query->have_posts()) : // check if query have any post

    while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); // start loop & set post global 
      // Get category slug parent info
      $category = get_the_category();
      $cat_slug = $category[0]->slug;
      $cat_name = $category[0]->name;
      $cat_url =  get_category_link( $category[0]->cat_ID );
      $post_date_month = get_the_date('M');
      $post_date_year = get_the_date('Y');


      $exclude_posts[] = get_the_ID();

?><div itemid="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" itemscope class="<?php if( $active ){ echo 'active'; $active = false; } ?>" style="position :relative;" itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
<header class="header-item">
  <a class="link-img" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
      <?php the_post_thumbnail('tab-slider', array( 'class' => 'img-responsive') ); ?>
  </a>
  <div class="date-box"><?php
      echo $post_date_month.'<br/>';
      echo '<small>'.$post_date_year.'</small>';
  ?></div>
  </header><!-- /header -->
  <div class="carousel-caption"> 
    <h4  itemprop="name"><?php if( $active ){ echo 'active'; $active = false; } ?><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
    <p class="meta-cat"><small><span class="inline-categ-icon visible-xs-block visible-sm-block icon-<?php echo $cat_slug;?>"></span>  Dans <a href="<?php echo $cat_url;?>" title="Voir les articles dans la rubrique « <?php echo $cat_name;?> » "><?php echo $cat_name;?></a></small></p>
    <p class="most-view-excerpt"><?php echo excerpt(27); ?></p>
    <?php $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpb_post_views_count', true);?>
    <div itemprop="interactionStatistic" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/InteractionCounter">
      <link itemprop="interactionType" href="http://schema.org/WatchAction"/>
      <meta itemprop="userInteractionCount" content="<?php echo $meta; ?>" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <p><a class="read-more" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="Lire notre article <?php the_title(); ?>">Lire le reportage</a></p>
</div>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: If all is working good, just mark this question as solve by using the check mark beside my answer

Comment: Done bynicolas ;)

Comment: I added some info to the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44725/discussion-on-answer-by-bynicolas-counter-in-loop-in-foreach)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

Ok so after better understanding your issue, I would not use a counter but a true/false flag that we switch when it's been used. Try this code.

```
$cats = array('batiments-delevage', 'logements-bovin', 'stockages-deffluents', 'soins-et-hygiene');
$exclude_posts = array();
$active = true;
foreach( $cats as $cat ) :
  // build query argument
  $query_args = array(
  'category_name' => $cat,
  'posts_per_page'=> 1,
  'post_type'     => 'post',
  'post_status'   => 'publish',
  'meta_key'      => 'wpb_post_views_count', //custom field for view count
  'orderby'       => 'meta_value_num',
  'order'         => 'DESC'
);

// exclude post that already have been fetched
// this would be useful if multiple category is assigned for same post
if( !empty($exclude_posts) )
  $query_args['post__not_in'] = $exclude_posts;

// do query
$query = new WP_Query( $query_args );

if ($query->have_posts()) : // check if query have any post

  while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); // start loop & set post global 
    // Get category slug parent info
    $category = get_the_category();
    $cat_slug = $category[0]->slug;
    $cat_name = $category[0]->name;
    $cat_url =  get_category_link( $category[0]->cat_ID );
    $post_date_month = get_the_date('M');
    $post_date_year = get_the_date('Y');


    $exclude_posts[] = get_the_ID();

?><div class="item <?php if( $active ){ echo 'active'; $active = false; } ?>">
  <header class="header-item">
    <a class="link-img" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
      <?php the_post_thumbnail('tab-slider', array( 'class' => 'img-responsive') ); ?>
    </a>
    <div class="date-box"><?php
      echo $post_date_month.'<br/>';
      echo '<small>'.$post_date_year.'</small>';
  ?></div>
  </header><!-- /header -->
    <div class="carousel-caption"> 
      <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
      <p class="meta-cat"><small><span class="inline-categ-icon visible-xs-block visible-sm-block icon-<?php echo $cat_slug;?>"></span>  Dans <a href="<?php echo $cat_url;?>" title="Voir les articles dans la rubrique « <?php echo $cat_name;?> » "><?php echo $cat_name;?></a></small></p>
      <p class="most-view-excerpt"><?php echo excerpt(27); ?></p>
    </div>
    <p><a class="read-more" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="Lire notre article <?php the_title(); ?>">Lire le reportage</a></p>
  </div>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**ORIGINAL**

You don't need a counter to do the job, you can use the [`current_post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) property of the current object which returns the index of the current object

so instead of using

`if ($i == 0)`

try

`if( 0 == $query->current_post )`

and get rid of your counters

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44725/discussion-on-answer-by-bynicolas-counter-in-loop-in-foreach).